# process.env.NODE_ENV always 'development' when building nestjs app with nrwl nx

Tags: nestjs, nrwl, nrwl-nx

My NX application's `npm run build:server` calls `ng build api-server` that triggers the `@nrwl/node:build` builder.

It builds the NestJS application as `main.js`. Things work except I wanted `process.env.NODE_ENV` to be evaluated at runtime but I think it was resolved at build time (via Webpack).

Currently, the value is always set to 'development'.

I am new to Nrwl's NX. Any solution this?

Answer (score 18):

In NestJs/Nodejs app in Nx.Dev workspace process.env.NODE_ENV is replaced during compilation from typescript to javascript very "smart way" to "development" string constant (everything like NODE_ENV is replaced). I don't know why. But only way how can I get real NODE_ENV in runtime is this code:

```
//process.env.NODE_ENV
process.env['NODE' + '_ENV']
```

Comment: I've got the exact same problem with NestJs, and I'm really surprised by your workaround, but it works so thank you !

Do you mind share a link or an explanation about the reasons concerning the override of NODE_ENV ?

And I'm really curious about the difference at runtime between process.env.NODE_ENV and process.env['NODE' + '_ENV'] too.

Comment: @ondřej-wagenknecht I tried and it did solve the issue and get the real NODE_ENV. I imagined that the problem was Nx overwriting the variable. I would also want to to know why does this work. Do you have any link or explanation?

Comment: Yeah, that's really interesting why this works - I can only think of nx looking through code and replacing `process.env.NODE_ENV` occurences and this solution works because splitting it like that doesn't match regex anymore

Comment: This just gave me `undefined` in React. :(

Answer (score 11):

The reason you're seeing development is because you're building the app in development mode - it's not best practice to evaluate at runtime because then the builder can't do fancy things to make the build production ready. If you want production, you need to build the app in production mode by adding the --prod flag (just like how you need to build Angular in production mode).

If you need to serve the app in production mode (instead of build) the default config doesn't provide you with a prod mode for serve. You'll need to add the configuration to your angular.json.

So this code:

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "api-server:build"
      }
    },
```

Would become

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "api-server:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "api-server:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
```

and then you can run

```
ng serve --project=api-server --prod
```

Answer (score 9):

Indeed the nx builder will replace the expression `process.env.NODE_ENV` in our source code with the current value of the env var (or the nx-mode).

What happens is this:

- the build command executes the [nx builder](https://nx.dev/l/a/node/build) which creates a configuration for [web-pack](https://webpack.js.org/)
- this configuration instructions for the [webpack-define plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to replace the text `process.env.NODE_ENV` during compilation with the actual value of the env-var (or the nx-mode):
  see nx-code [getClientEnvironment()](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/11.4.0/packages/web/src/utils/config.ts#L201)

Since the [webpack-define plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) will look for the text `process.env.NODE_ENV`, it's easy to use a workaround as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59805161/1041641):

```js
process.env['NODE'+'_ENV']
```

**Warning**
When you need to apply this workaround to make your app work, then something is wrong. Since you have compiled your app in production mode, it does not make sense to pass another value for `NODE_ENV` when you start the (production) app.
The [webpack Production page](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-mode) contains some helpful info.

We also had this case, and the issue was, that we relied on the `NODE_ENV` variable to load different database configs for dev, prod, test, etc.
The solution for our case was to simply use separate env-vars for the database config (e.g. `DB_NAME`, `DB_PORT`, ..), so that we can use different db-configs at runtime with any build-variants: dev, prod, test, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem using Express instead of Nest.
What we did to overcome this was  adding some file replacements when compiling for any of our environments (development, production, staging, staging-dev). This is done in the angular.json file the same way the environment files are replaced for the Angular app .

Another approach that worked for us, was loading the environment variables only once, and retrieve them from that origin. As our app relies on Express for it's backend the used the Express env variable as:

```
import express from 'express';

const _app = express();
const _env = _app.get('env');

console.log(_env); // shows the right environment value set on NODE_ENV
```

To come to this conclusion we checked Express code for the env variable and it does use  process.env.NODE_ENV internally.

Hope it helps. Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

We had the same issue, we eventually used the cross-env package in our package.json:

"prodBuild": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nx run api-server:build:production",
"prodServe": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nx run api-server:serve:production"

Answer (score -4):

`process.env` is indeed only available at run-time. What is probably happening is that you are not setting this value when running your application. Can I ask how you are running it?

As a trivial example

```
# The following will read the environment variables that are defined in your shell (run `printenv` to see what those are)
> node main.js

# this will have your variable set
> NODE_ENV=production node main.js
```

Of course you want to have it actually set in your environment when deploying the app rather then passing it in this way, but if you're doing it locally you can do it like this.

Comment: I ran the webpack built app using "NODE_ENV=xxx node main.js". The value of process.env.NODE_ENV is still "development" instead of "xxx".