# Heroku NODE_ENV is always "development" despite setting config var to "staging" (NestJS app)

Tags: heroku, config, nestjs, typeorm, dotenv

In my Heroku environment where I deploy my NestJS application, I set all my Config Vars through the Heroku UI. I have set my `NODE_ENV` config var to `staging` using the Heroku UI. I've even ran this command `heroku config:set NODE_ENV=staging -a <my-staging-environment`. When I run `heroku config -a <my-staging-environment>`, I see that `NODE_ENV` is set to `staging`, but for whatever reason, when I console.log this variable from my code, it outputs `development`. Below is some example code where it is logs `development` as the value for `NODE_ENV` in my TypeOrm configuration. This is causing the `ssl` property to not get set to the correct value, and I cannot connect to my Heroku Postgres database because of it. I only intend to set it to `development` for local development purposes.

```
require('dotenv').config();

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // outputs "development" - idk where this value is coming from
console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL); // outputs the correct value that I set in Heroku Config Vars

const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' ? { rejectUnauthorized: false } : false, // ternary evaluates to the wrong value
  // ... other config options
};
```

I use `dotenv`, and I made sure to `.gitignore` my `.env` file. I don't recall ever setting this variable to `development`. The only place I see it set to `NODE_ENV=development` in my code is in my `.env-example` file. I do commit this file to source control, but it's just an example file and not a real `.env` file and it shouldn't actually be being used.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is not a Heroku issue. Rather it is a NestJS/Nx issue.

See:
[process.env.NODE_ENV always 'development' when building nestjs app with nrwl nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58090082/process-env-node-env-always-development-when-building-nestjs-app-with-nrwl-nx)

Comment: Congrats! Since you've solved the issue can you set this answer as **Accepted Answer**. Thanks!